# Access terraform provider from a parent or sibling module

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to access a tf provider from a parent or sibling module?

```
tf
  module1
    module2
    module3
```

Given the hierarchy above.

1) Can a provider defined in module2 be used in module3?

2) Can a provider defined in module2 be used in module1?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform provider configurations can only propagate downwards into child modules.

[The recommended approach](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#providers-within-modules) is to have provider configurations only in the root module, and then either pass them explicitly or have them automatically inherit into the descendant modules.